# node express - unformatted json in chrome

Tags: json, node.js, express

I use express in my node App to send a JSON response:

```
App.get('/shops', function (req, res) {
    res.json(200, {
        success: true,
        reason: 'data found correctly',
        shops: shops
    });
}
```

If in Chrome I go to 127.0.0.1:port/shops I see the response as a string (all in one line);
is it possible to send the JSON answer formatted?

Before (with a less recent version of express) I was using something like

```
answer = JSON.stringify(answer, null, '\t');   // answer is a js object
res.send(200, answer);
```

But now (with express 4) even if I try something like that I see in the browser one row with many \n and \t inside of it;

Don't know if it is due to express version...

Comment: Is this a new build/project? If so, why aren't you leveraging Express 4?

Comment: yes, sorry I'm using express 4.4.4; it has been an error ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json spaces` setting sets the indent character for JSON output.  To enable pretty printing, do the following to your application:

```
var app = express();
app.set('json spaces', '  ');
// ...
```

As of 2014-06-24, this is not currently documented in the [Express 4 API](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html), but the behaviour can be found in [the source code for `res.json`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L204):

```
var spaces = app.get('json spaces');
var body = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, spaces);
```